# Problem with getting Excel cell background colors in C#

Tags: c#, excel, colors

I am trying to get background color of some cells in an Excel sheet in C#.
I am using follwoing code for it:

```
Excel.Range r = (Excel.Range)m_objRange[i, j];                                  
int decValue = int.Parse(r.Interior.Color.ToString());
string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
```

So i get the long decimal value and then i convert into hex to use it into an html code.
Now i have a problem in getting the right colors. For example:

Case 1.

Actual Color-Red

Returned Decimal value-255

Corresponing Hex value- FF (or 0000FF)

Corresponing color i got- Blue

Case 2.

Actual Color-Blue

Returned Decimal value-16711680

Corresponing Hex value- FF0000

Corresponing color i got- Red

Case 3.

Actual Color-Green

Returned Decimal value-32768

Corresponing Hex value- 8000

Corresponing color i got- White

Now in case 1, i guess i should interpret hex value of FF as #FF0000 to get it as red?
In case 3, i should interpret hex value of 8000 as #008000 to get is a green?

Is there a way where i can directly get six digit hex value which would be exactly the color that i want?
I am getting wrong decimal values or I am not converting decimal into hex properly?

And what is happening in Case 2? Here i am getting six digit hex value but it is completely wrong. FF0000 is clearly red and not blue.

Answer (score 10):

This work for me:

```
int colorNumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(((Range) worksheet.Cells[rowNumber,columnNumber]).Interior.Color);
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(colorNumber);
```

Comment: I have same requirement to read cell color I use your above suggested code. But with this code I got only white color , But in excel there is other color as well like Red,Blue. Can u please help me to sort out it?

Comment: @dwan I would suggest check if you are getting the color from the correct cell. Make sure you have the correct rowNumber and columnNumber.

Comment: What if I want to check a column, for each cell in the column, if it has a fill, delete that entire row until every cell in the column has been checked?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
System.Color col = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle((int) r.Interior.Color);
string htmlCol = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(col);
```

(warning, I didn't test this)

Comment: This doesn't work in c#. ColorTranslator.FromOle(System.Drawing.Color) takes System.Drawing.Color as a parameter and hence if i pass it r.Interior.Color I get an error that you cannot convert int to System.Drawing.Color

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking at ToOle()?  I see FromOle() takes an int.