# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reading false color?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

```
tmp.Color = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Interior.Color.ToString();
```

I read the Cellcolor of an excel document like this, but I get not the color I expect: 
16777215 for aquamarine for example but it´s not the value for aquamarine, it´s the value for yellow. Am I reading the cellcolor not right?

Comment: Try to get the value of color with System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Interior.Color); this will return you a Color value, does this return the correct value?

Comment: it throws an error that it conatins invalid arguments

Comment: Property `Color` returns value as `double` (dynamic). You need to convert it to `int` before passing to `ColorTranslator.FromOle`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found solution for you, And hope this will work for you.

```
int colorNumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(((Range) worksheet.Cells[rowNumber,columnNumber]).Interior.Color);
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(colorNumber);
```

Refrence link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1867695/6923146